Why does `git --allow-unrelated-histories` not seem to work?
I have numerous Git repos with various scripts, and I'm in the process of merging them all into one. I want to preserve the commit history for each script, however.
I did this successfully, for the first repo, a couple of weeks ago, following the steps in this article. But when I tried just now for the next repo, the history doesn't seem to be coming across.
I've changed the directory structure for the next repo, which I'll call the 'old repo', to fit into the new all-in-one repo. I've committed that, and verified that the history is still attached to the script I want to merge.
Then I did this:
cd ../new-repo
git remote add -f old-repo ../old-repo
git fetch old-repo # I didn't do this the fist time I tried today
git merge old-repo/master --no-commit --allow-unrelated-histories
git log --follow bin/old-repo-script

The history didn't appear. Nothing did, even though the article says:

You can also run git log at this point to check that the commit messages were also merged in

It seems they weren't, even though when I followed the same steps for the other repo, I'm pretty sure they showed up at this stage.
I've aborted the merge and tried again a few times, including:

pointing a branch in the old repo to a commit with the script in the original location, and merging that
creating a remote with an absolute path to the repo
fetching the repo first (as shown above)
checking out different branches in the old repo and then the master again, and then fetching it again

The script gets staged each time, but I don't see its history, even though it still appears when I do a git log old-repo-script in the old repo.
What might I be doing wrong today?
FWIW, I'm using Git version 2.34.1 under Linux.

"git merge … --no-commit" — what merge commit do you expect in the log?

@phd: I don't expect to see a merge commit in the log at this stage, but I do expect to see the commits from that file, copied from the old repo. The article I linked to says I should, and I'm pretty sure I did, when I tried it a few weeks ago.

Well, I tried with my two small unrelated repositories, and the log didn't appear until I finished merge (i.e., committed).

Try git log --all --follow bin/old-repo-script

@phd: --all made it appear, and sure enough, after I did the commit, I didn't need that switch. Perhaps I wasn't so careful last time. Thanks—if you write that advice as an answer, I'll accept it.

I tried this in a test repo and got the same results as you and @phd — but git log --all works as expected. It makes sense that git log wouldn't update until the merge is actually committed (not just staged).
(I'm the author of the blog post in question, and simply got this wrong. Apologies! I've updated and corrected the post now.)

No worries. I appreciate you jumping in.
